# Вызов метода для каждого базового класса вариативного шаблонного класса-наследника

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

Есть такой вариативный шаблонный класс:

```
template<class ... Data>
class BookOrder: public Data ... {
public:
    enum OrderStatus {Accepted, Verifying, Cancelled, BookAbsent, Fulfilled};
    OrderStatus status;
    BookOrder(const Data& ... data): Data(data)... {
        status = BookOrder::OrderStatus::Accepted;
    }
    std::string getInfo(void) const;
};
```

Я хочу реализовать метод getInfo таким образом, чтобы он возвращал конкатенацию всех строк, полученных вызовами метода getInfo у всех базовых   классов. Реализовую вот так, но компилятор выдает ошибку.

```
template <class ... Data>
std::string BookOrder<Data ...>::getInfo(void) const {
    std::string res;
    res += "   " + Data::getInfo()...;
    return res;
}
```

> error: expected ‘;’ before ‘...’ token
>        res += "   " + Data::getInfo()...;
>
> error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
>        res += "   " + Data::getInfo()...;

Как правильно сделать распаковку вариативных параметров шаблона?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у тебя не C++17, то ... умеет раскрываться только в сущности разделяемые запятой. Решение:

```
std::string baseInfo[]={ Data::getInfo()... };
std::string res;
for( auto& i : baseInfo ) res += "   " + i ;
return s;
```